# How can I stream different lines of input from one text file?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to create a simulation in which I have objects moving within a rectangular grid. Information is given in the form of a text file. Sample input is as follows:

```
5 5
0 1 N
PFPFFSF
2 3 S
FSFFSFFSPF
```

First line is the dimension of the grid (in this case 5 x 5 assuming the bottom left coordinate is 0,0)

The rest of the input is just info in regards to the object and how it moves. Each object has 2 lines of input. First line is it's starting coordinates and orientation while the second line describes its movements.

When using an input stream, how can I grab the input so that it groups accordingly?

I know for the first line, I can just use

```
simulationSettings >> x >> y;
```

to grab the size of the grid.

However, is there a way of grabbing the rest of the input and grouping the info by 2 lines (for each object)?

So, for example, stream the input so that my object1 will have 0 1 N and PFPFFSF while object 2 has 2 3 S and FSFFSFFPF and so on should there be more objects.

Comment: If the input file is not very large, read all inputs as objects in vectors. Now you can do in whatever order you want with these objects.

Comment: @MohitJain This is just a sample input. I need it to work with however many amount of lines. I'm wondering whether I can have my program recognize while streaming to just group 2 lines at a time after the 1st line.

Comment: Length of lines in input file is not same. So random access is not practical here. You need some way to find the offset of the start of input lines.

Comment: Do you need to read it in lines to detect errors in the input file, or can you assume that the structure of the file is fine and read (in that order): 2 ints for the grid size, and n * (2 ints and 2 strings) no matter how the lines are actually organized?

Comment: @ Serge Ballesta I forgot that the operator >> will read until the next white space so I can just do while (simulationSettings >> x >> y >> orientation >> movement) right? I can still error test once I have those inputs.

Comment: you could try to utilize regular expresions to match each line to a pattern

Comment: @JKreiser: don't you think that regexes are overkill here?

Comment: @trungnt: if you do not need to control where the lines end, it should be enough.

Comment: @SergeBallesta that would be good enough for me. Thanks for spurring my memory. I was looking at things by lines rather than white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can simply ignore how the file is actually structured in line, you structure is just:

- 2 integer values for the grid size
- n times (per object):

  - 2 integers for the initial position
  - one string for the initial direction
  - one string for the movements

You could just use:

```
simulationSettings >> x >> y;
if (! simulationSettings.good()) {
    // process error condition and exit
}
for(;;) {
    int xinit, yinit;
    std::string direction, movements;
    simulationSettings >> xinit;
    if (simulationSettings.eof()) break; // normal end of file
    simulationSetting >> yinit >> direction >> movements;
    if (! simulationSettings.good()) {
        // process error condition and at least break from the loop
    }
    // process the object
}
```